# Restlet converter registration in OSGI environment

Tags: osgi, restlet, restlet-2.0

We run Restlet 2.1 in an OSGi environment (Equinox) as bundle (ie. not as library within a bundle). The problem is that the Restlet Engine does not detect helpers (like converters) that are provided by Restlet extensions. Specifically, the `EngineClassLoader#getResources()` call does not return any result. The extensions are also deployed as OSGi bundles in the target platform.

Is automatic converter registration actually supposed to work within OSGi environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, Restlet supports such feature thanks to a dedicated activator (see the Activator class in the package org.restlet.engine.internal).

This activator introspects bundles to find out the following things:

- servers corresponding to registered servers
- servers corresponding to registered clients
- authenticators corresponding to registered clients
- converters

Be aware that to use this feature, we must use the OSGi edition of Restlet since it's the only that has the MANIFEST file of the org.restlet bundle with the activator class specified. Otherwise you don't have to care about the bundle loading order...

Hope it helps you.
Thierry

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I use the OSGi edition of restlet, but the automatic registration didn't work anyway. I'm going to check if the activator is invoked and how it behaves.

Comment: As it turned out, the org.restlet bundle wasn't started at all (I assumed it would activate automatically when one if its classes is loaded, which is not the case). Maybe I missed this point in the restlet documentation. I'm going to accept this answer, as it resolves my problem.

Comment: Normally, the org.restlet bundle should be started when the equinox container is started. If you try to start manually using the "start <bundle-id>", have you an error? Can you also give us the bundle list present in the container (with ss command)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unless the Restlet-bundle explicitly imports the packages that contain the extensions (and I doubt it does, and it shouldn't), it wouldn't be able to load them, because bundles have isolated class-spaces.

A possible solution would be to provide the extensions as [fragments](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Fragment) attached to the Restlet-bundle. Thus, if you make it use the bundle-classloader ([the documentation](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.1/android/engine/org/restlet/engine/util/EngineClassLoader.html) says this can be done by [setting the `Engine`s classloader](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/2.1/android/engine/org/restlet/engine/Engine.html#setClassLoader%28java.lang.ClassLoader%29)), it would be able to load classes from the fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it doesn't quite work for OSGi, as it depends on the ability to see the entire class space.

The way to do this in OSGi would be to use the service registry for the extensions, but that only works for OSGi aware libraries.

There is *some* help on the way: In the recently released [OSGi 5 (Service Loader Mediator)](http://blog.osgi.org/2012/06/core-release-5-and-enterprise-release-5.html) there will be support to 'bridge' META-INF/services (I don't know if Restlet uses those, though) onto OSGi services, so 'legacy' libraries should work well within OSGi.

There is an implementation in Apache Aries called [Spi-Fly](http://aries.apache.org/modules/spi-fly.html). I looked at it briefly a while back. It might do the trick for you, it might not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed the accepted answer to Thierry's, though, because it resolves my problem for now. But the mentioned Service Loader Mediator is helpful for the future anyway.

Comment: Sure thing, that what it is all about. If it is helpful you can upvote it.